# Counterintuitive surface integral

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals, arc-length, solid-of-revolution

The area of a surface of revolution $y(x)$ is express by the integral
$$A=\int\limits_a^b 2\pi y(x)\underbrace{\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}}_\text{arc length of y(x) at x}dx$$

But this seems counter-intuitive to me. Consider the volume integral
$$V=\int\limits_a^b \pi y(x)^2dx$$
Here we don't use the arc length, but why? In the integral for $A$, it seems that we just need to take infinitesimal circle lengths at $x$ multiplied by infinitesimal width $dx$:
$$A=\int\limits_a^b 2\pi y(x)dx$$

I would appreciate if someone could please clarify this for me strictly conceptually / geometrically.

Comment: It's just uses the Pythagorean theorem with catheti $dx$ and $dy$. You can't just ignore $dy$: for, say, $y(x)=x$ the catheti are equal.

Comment: Maybe it would help to go back to thinking about the integral for arclength, and why you can't just add up all the $\Delta x$'s instead of $\Delta s$'s.

Comment: @TedShifrin Why don't we take $ds$ into account when we calculate the volume?

Comment: Because volume of a box is width times cross-sectional area. There is nothing to do with $ds$.

Comment: Oh, I got it, thanks. For the area, we need to multiply the circumference of the cylinder by its length. If the "cylinder" is now curved, we need to know the length of the curve, not the horizontal length of the "cylinder". Now it makes sense.